# graph theory how can we show the inequality?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices. Suppose that $G$ has $k$ components. If $m$ is the number of edges in $G$, show that
$$
n−k ≤ m ≤ \frac{(n−k)(n−k + 1)}{2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Assume that each connected component contains $n_i$ vertices, and $m_i$ edges, $1\le i \le k$. We  have: 
  $$n_i - 1 \le m_i \le n_i(n_i-1)/2$$

So $$\sum_{i=1}^k(n_i-1) \le \sum_{i=1}^k m_i \le \sum_{i=1}^k n_i(n_i-1)/2$$

We also have $n=\sum_{i=1}^k n_i$, and $m=\sum_{i=1}^k m_i$, so the above inequality is simplified to

$$n-k \le m \le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k n_i^2 - n}{2}$$
Now we need to show that $$\sum_{i=1}^k n_i^2 \le (n+1-k)^2 + (k-1)$$ given that $n=\sum_{I=1}^k n_i$ and $n_i \ge 1$, which is an easy exercise.

Comment: Very nice! I like your approach.

Comment: I think you should detail the last inequality though.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it exactly:)

Comment: @EyüpGüler thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both inequalities come easily if you consider the "extreme" case -- that is, the case of $k$ component graphs having as many edges as possible. This happens when all the component graphs are complete, and further, when all but one component graph is $K_1$. To see this last point, suppose there are two component graphs, say $K_r$ and $K_s$ with $r \ge s > 1$. Now take a vertex of $K_s$ having $s-1$ edges and add it to $K_r$ giving it $r$ edges. You've just increased the number of edges of $G$ without increasing the number of vertices. So the extreme cases hold, and the number of edges of $G$ is less than or equal to the number of edges in the complete graph $K_{n-k}$.